# Option to vertically split screen for post preview

Tags: feature-request, usability, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preview on the right please, optionally?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53484/preview-on-the-right-please-optionally)

For longer posts, e.g. answers on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) that involve a lot of MathJax equations, but also if lot's of code is involved at SO, it might be helpful to see the rendered preview on the right side of the screen instead of at the bottom, so one doesn't have to scroll all the time.

[image]

Comment: @animuson Thanks, I didn't find that one