# Long post edit and markdown preview

Tags: feature-request, editor, markdown-preview

When I write a post in SO, I use to watch the markdown preview very often. It is a bless that it is updated in real time.

However, when my post is long, **I have to scroll down the page** to look at at the markdown preview, **then scroll up** to fix things in the edit. This happens especially to long posts because when I correct something at the end, the preview portion that interrests me is out of sight.

So I would like to suggest a **Synced vertical scrollbar in the markdown preview**.

The idea is to **decide which portion of my post I want to see** in it. Additionally, having both markview edit and preview panes synced when I edit my post should help a lot.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53484/152859)?

Comment: Yes I did. But having edit and preview side by side is not applicable to everyone : I still often use a good old 4/3 display.

Comment: Fair enough; this sounds like a complicated change though so I doubt it's worth the effort. Up to the dev team! :)

Answer (score 2):

Discourse, the forum software developed by Jeff Atwood and others after he left StackOverflow, implements the autoscroll feature.

A more comprehensive solution would be to display the Markdown preview side-by-side, and I started a feature request for that at [The Discourse layout for side-by-side Markdown preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253112/the-discourse-layout-for-side-by-side-markdown-preview).