# Design issue of Stack Overflow In IE6

Tags: support, design, internet-explorer-6

As I am a web developer I always appreciate browser compatible code and design.

So far I was very much satisfied with the minute details kept by Stack overflow team in functioning as well as design, but today when I logged into my account through IE6 I am getting some horozontal space over header, also think this is the issue in IE6 due to 1 `<div id="overlay-header">`

Even I started promoting this application to my colleages in this four days.Just want this designing bug to be removed.

Removing this bugs will create great place in my mind for stackoverflow.

Comment: Ya I too accept the fact.Also I want stack overflow to resolve .png image problems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer to your question: No, not going to happen.

Robert answered the question very well [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34653/how-to-fix-sos-questions-page-in-ie6/34707#34707).

The short version: SO will only guarantee the rendering of text in IE6, and will not be addressing or fixing any layout issues with IE6.

Since even Microsoft no longer support IE6, I am not at all surprised at this decision.

Comment: Though stack overflow doesn't look that bad in IE6,still I am proud to be a part of this application.Thaks for the link

Answer (score -6):

Going to happen or not going to happen is not the issue here.
Designing application for every browser is what I have been taught.Smooth functioning of Stack Overflow should be considered on every browser.

Comment: Why you are favouring IE6.No one loves IE. I hate this two alphabets.

Comment: @Wakar - by your reasoning then the website should also be perfect in Netscape 2.0, IE 3.0, and Lynx. After all, they're a part of "every browser"

Comment: @FarSeeker: Please be reasonable. It would be enough that the website be perfect in any browser the same age as IE6 or newer. Check out this chart, Netscape 4.8, Opera 6 and FF 0.9 would qualify! http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Timeline_of_web_browsers.svg